# My Javascript doesn't wait for an ajax call to finish

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am currently writing the code for a register validation in Javascript, one of the things the validation function checks is wether or not the email adress provided by the user is already in the database.

To check this I am using ajax, but the rest of my Javascript doesn't wait for it to finish.

I tried many solutions I found on the web but nothing seems to work.

This is my form:

```
<form class="register-form" id="register-form" action="register.php" method="post" onSubmit="return registervalidation()">
  <input name="username" id="registerusername" type="text" placeholder="gebruikersnaam" maxlength="20"/>
  <input name="password" id="registerpassword" type="password" placeholder="wachtwoord" maxlength="20"/>
  <input name="email" id="registeremail" type="text" placeholder="emailadres" maxlength="50"/>
  <p class="error" id="register-error"></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Aanmaken"/>
  <p class="message">Heb je al een account? <a href="#">Log in</a></p>
</form>
```

This is the Javascript code:

```
<script>

var invalid = 0;

function registervalidation() {

    invalid = 0;
    document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML = "";

    if (document.getElementById("registerusername").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML = "Gelieve een gebruikersnaam in te typen.<br>";
        invalid += 1;
    }

    else {
        if (document.getElementById("registerusername").value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)) {
            /* Input is oke */
        }
        else {
            /* Input is niet oke */
            document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML = "Een gebruikersnaam mag enkel bestaan letters en cijfers.<br>";
            invalid += 1
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById("registerpassword").value == "") {
        var red = document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML = red + "Gelieve een wachtwoord in te typen.<br>";
        invalid += 1;
    }

    else {
        if (document.getElementById("registerpassword").value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)) {
            /* Input is oke */
        }
        else {
            /* Input is niet oke */
            var red = document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML = red + "Een wachtwoord mag enkel bestaan uit letters en cijfers.<br>";
            invalid += 1;
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById("registeremail").value == "") {
        var red = document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML = red + "Gelieve een emailadres in te typen.<br>";
        invalid += 1;
    }

    else {

        if (document.getElementById("registeremail").value.indexOf("@") == -1) {
            var red = document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML = red + "Gelieve een geldig emailadres in te typen.<br>";
            invalid += 1;
    }

    else {

        var checkmail = $('#registeremail').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: "validation.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'email=' + checkmail,
        success: function(result){
             if(result == null){
             }
             else{
            var red = document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML = red + "Dit emailadres is reeds in gebruik.<br>";
            invalid += 1;
             }
           }
  });


    }

    }

    if (invalid != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    else {
        return true;
    }
}

</script>
```

And this is my validation.php file:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/json');

//no need to continue if there is no value in the POST username
if(!isset($_POST['email']))
    exit;

//initialize our PDO class. You will need to replace your database credentials respectively
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cheapgamer','root','',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

//prepare our query.
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = :email');
//let PDO bind the username into the query, and prevent any SQL injection attempts.
$query->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
//execute the query
$query->execute();

//return the json object containing the result of if the username exists or not. The $.post in our jquery will access it.
echo json_encode(array('exists' => $query->rowCount() > 0));
?>
```

The validation works perfectly fine, just not when the only error is the email adress being already in the database.

Thanks in advance!

Dennis

Comment: You do realize that XHR requests are **asynchronous**? You can't return true or false from a function that starts an XHR request. This isn't PHP and it doesn't behave like that.

Comment: @N.B. I see, but how would you solve this problem?

Comment: AJAX request is asynchronous which means the code after the AJAX won't wait for AJAX to complete its request. That is, AJAX can take its own time to complete its request based on the network performance. So, the other code won't wait for AJAX completion.

Comment: Don't create functions that return true or false because it doesn't work that way. When the response comes back, you have `success` callback in your `$.ajax`, do the logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Create an function and put your javascript code that you want to stop till ajax gets complete.

Now call that function from inside of ajax success function. So that code will not be executed till ajax gets complete.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests, as the name says, are asynchronous, so your code will continue to  execute. You can solve this problem by always returning `false` on `function registervalidation`, and upon a valid response from PHP, you call the method `submit()` from your form.

```
var checkmail = $('#registeremail').val();
$.ajax({
  url: "validation.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'email=' + checkmail,
  success: function(result){
    if (result != null){
      var red = document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("register-error").innerHTML = red + "Dit emailadres is reeds in gebruik.<br>";
      invalid += 1;
    } else {
      // Call $(form).submit();
    }
  }
});
```

Now, bear in mind that you'll have to refactor your `onSubmit` attribute, otherwise it'll execute over and over again.